# Compiling shaders in Vulcan, "Create a compile.bat file?" Windows 10 Visual Studio

Tags: shader, vulkan

Hi I was following [this Vulkan tutorial](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/en/Drawing_a_triangle/Graphics_pipeline_basics/Shader_modules) and I just don't know what they mean by

Create a `compile.bat` file with the following contents:

`C:/VulkanSDK/x.x.x.x/Bin32/glslc.exe shader.vert -o vert.spv`
`C:/VulkanSDK/x.x.x.x/Bin32/glslc.exe shader.frag -o frag.spv`
`pause`

This is in the link under "Compiling the Shaders."

What is a `compile.bat` file? Where do I create it? I tried entering in these commands but with the appropriate version and it just says it can't find shader.frag or shader.vert, which I created in my project just as the tutorial instructed. I'm using Visual Studio on Windows 10.

I think it is assuming some command line savviness with this tutorial which I do not have lol I know basic stuff like mkdir and cd but that is pretty much it. And it looks like the `.spv` files have to go into the `shaders` directory in my project but those commands don't refer to that directory. And later, you just read the bytes from vert.spv and frag.spv like `readFile("shaders/vert.spv")` so what is the compile.bat file even for? Thank you.

Comment: `bat` is a batch file. You just create a text file and name it that. In the text file you just can have those commands. If it cannot find `shader.frag`, then that means there is not any in the current working directory. You need to navigate to the place `shader.frag` is by using `cd`.

Comment: Where do I create the `.bat` file? Anywhere? I tried putting it in my source folder and in the shaders folder and both times double-clicking the file does nothing. It says that double-clicking it should run it.

Comment: Most conveniently in the place where the `shader.frag` is. Double-clicking should indeed run it, and the `pause` command should wait for you to press a key before the window gets closed.

Comment: Ok I did that and opened it up in file explore so I could double-click the `.bat` file to run it and it created the `.spv` files but I don't see them in my project in Visual Studio? So I just drag and dropped them in from file explore. I'm gonna do the rest of the tutorial to make sure it works but so far thanks!

Comment: Ya after changing the file path from `shaders/vert.spv` to just 'vert.spv` it works now. Weird because those shaders are in a directory called `shaders` so I don't know why this works. But I finally have a triangle on my screen after 900 lines of code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@krOoze helped me in the comments: you create the compile.bat in the shaders folder, put the commands in the compile.bat file. Then, open your project in file explorer and double-click on the .bat file to run it.

Comment: Path should have `\\` in Windows.